# Finding the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

May someone help me with this problem in finding the matrix $T \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that
$$
T \begin{pmatrix}  1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}  3 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}
\\
T \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Couldn't you just set up and solve a system of equations and solve for each component? (eg $T_{11},T_{12}$...) It seems like this would be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

$$T\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\-2 & -1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 \\10 & -5\end{pmatrix}$$

Solve for $T$.

$$T=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 \\10 & -5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\-2 & -1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

Another approach without matrix inversion explicitly. Let $T=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}.$

We end up with $$a-2b=3$$
$$c-2d=10$$
$$-2a-b=-1$$
$$-2c-d=-5$$

Solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: The answer is ?

Comment: good question. hmm... have you tried? where do you get stuck.

Comment: What am i supposed to do?

Comment: $T$ is of the form of $AB^{-1}$. Are you able to compute $B^{-1}$? After which, compute $AB^{-1}$.

Comment: Why did you put it in the inverse form???

Comment: What does -1 mean in matrices? Inverse?

Comment: Yup, matrix inverse. $B^{-1}$ has the property that $BB^{-1}=I$.

Comment: Ok so $AI$ which tells me what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41482/discussion-between-siongthyegoh-and-shammy).